# Remove Sensor Voltage Offset ADC

Tags: signal, dc-offset

I've got a pressure sensor and a flow sensor. Both have a 5V span, but have a (different) null offset i.e. at zero pressure (gauge) or zero flow they read ~2V and ~1V respectively.

I am using an [ADS1256 ADC](http://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/ads1256) and PiPyADC (from git) so can only read up to 5V. How can I remove these offsets?

Git code has a function:

```
|  cal_self_offset(self)
|      Perform an input zero calibration using chip-internal
|      reference switches.
|      
|      Sets the ADS1255/ADS1256 OFC register.
```

but I'm not sure that's what I need, I definitely can't make it do what I want anyway!

Currently, my only thought is to step the voltage down over a 2/3 potential divider to get into range, though I'm bound to lose some accuracy this way. I'm hoping I can somehow remove the offsets from both sensors.

I appreciate any help/guidance,

Thanks.

Comment: The ADS1256 input is differential, so you could just trim the negative input to the zero level of the sensor.

Comment: So say my sensor is reading 2-7V and I make the negative input 2, will it then read the 7V signal as 5V differentially? As it only has a supply & reference of 5V..

Comment: The analog inputs shouldn't go above 5V, so if you want the whole range, you will have to modify the sensor output before feeding it to the ADC.  Your idea of using a resistive divider will work, but you will still lose 2/3*Voffset at the low end of the ADC.  If you can accept that, then it is the easiest solution.  Make sure that the sensor output has the current to drive whatever divider you are using.

Comment: You forgot to mention which sensors you use, it can be important

Comment: If the output of the flow sensor is 0.3V, do you need to read that it is 0.7V below the zero-flow voltage of 1.0V?  Or can you accept a measurement of zero flow when in reality the voltage is below the zero-flow voltage?  Ditto for pressure.

Comment: Nope - happy to accept a measurement of zero flow/pressure when the voltage reads less than the "zero flow/pressure" offset if that's doable